# How to executes command in serial console using RS232Send in capl?

Tags: serial-port, capl

I want to execute a particular command in serial console .
I am able to open serial port and configuration everything is properly done .
But , i want to execute one command through serial port , for that i have used RS232Send inbuilt function in capl, but the command is not executed .
But received send success.  Can anyone help me how this can be done ?

```
{
long res;   
char text[20] = "Run task ";
byte buffer[20],rec_buf[100];
int i;
int length,size=100;
byte Port_Num = 4 ;
res = RS232Open(Port_Num) ;//Open serial port
if(res==1)
 write("opened port success.");
res=RS232Configure(Port_Num,115200,8,1,0);//Configure serial port
if(res==1)
  write("Configure Port4 Success."); 
length=strlen(text)+1;
for (i=0;i<length;i++)
{
buffer[i]=text[i];
write("%c",buffer[i]);
}
res = RS232Send(Port_Num,buffer,length); //Send data.
if ( res==1)
   write("send successs."); 
}
```

Comment: A return value of 1 from RS232Send only means that sending was started successfully. You should implement the callback handlers `RS232OnSend` and `RS232OnError` in order to get more information about what is going on.

Comment: @M.Spiller , Thanks now i am able to see with the handler , it is send properly . But , the command not executed properly . what shall we done to perform "Enter" operation  after executing the command .In real time it is like this , "run task" -> Press "Enter Key" , so too simulate this i have added "\n" along with the "run task \n" but it did not executed .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _Enter operation_. That all depends on what your receiver expects. Most likely there should be a newline at the end of the command. I.e. like `char text[20] = "Run task\r\n";` or `char text[20] = "Run task\n";`. But you should look that up in the documentation of the RS232 receiver.

Comment: i got the solution it was due to harware connection , recommended call back solution was helpful. Thank you @M